# Where to start when building a website from scratch using index.php

Tags: php

I have decided to build my site website from scratch, rather than using Wordpress, Magento or a bootstrap template.

I'm looking for a good guide to do so, Code Academy and w3schools are good for learning specific elements of HTML and CSS but I'm looking for a good guide for how to structure my site.

I am playing around with creating an index.php using e.g.  to include all element of the page to make creating the individual pages of my site clean and more efficient that including the include for header and footer on each page.

One issue I am having is that I am struggling to understand how to include the different pages within the index.php. I have searched for this but I obviously am not finding the correct words to search for this as I'm struggling to find a decent answer. I think I need something along the lines of a wildcard so that I can say  to call all html files within my pages folder so that all pages are using my index.php template.

Below is my index.php to help explain. Thanks in advance and apologies if this question is answered elsewhere on the site, I searched but did not find anyone else answering the same question!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <php include "head.html" ?>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <php include "navigation.html" ?>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <php include pages/*.html ?>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
    <php include "footer.html" ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are almost there. I am not sure of the syntax you are using works, but the code below is used in some of my sites to include a header:

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
```

This means include the code in the file 'header.php' that is in the folder 'includes', which is on the same level as the file that is calling the code.

The result would be that the 2 files are merged in to one when the page is loaded, with the code from header.php being inserted in place of the line

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass variables in URL e.g `index.php?page=home` and then in your index.php file you shoud get that variable `$page = $_GET['page']`. Now in `$page` you have name of the file to include

```
<?php include($page.'.html') ?>
```

For now, I skipped security issues of that solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this sounds to be what I need but I'm pretty new to PHP, any chance you could dumb this down for me a bit!!